# Memory leak when C program ran from bash script

Tags: c, bash, memory-leaks

I have a C program that takes various command line arguments, i.e

```
./Coupled arg1 argv2
```

And when I run this with valgrind as

```
valgrind ./Coupled arg1 arg2
```

I get no memory leaks. But when I use a bash script, called `run`, of the form

```
arg1=thing1
arg2=thing2

./Coupled $thing1 $thing2
```

and then run

```
valgrind ./run
```

I get a lot of still reachable memory leakage. I have read that that still reachable memory leakage isn't a huge problem, but I would quite like to know why this is happening? When running valgrind with `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` flags, an example bit of output (the full valgrind output is many pages long)

```
==4518== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 269
==4518==    at 0x4C29BE3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==4518==    by 0x46A3DA: xmalloc (in /usr/bin/bash)
==4518==    by 0x437219: make_variable_value (in /usr/bin/bash)
==4518==    by 0x438230: ??? (in /usr/bin/bash)
==4518==    by 0x43A35E: initialize_shell_variables (in /usr/bin/bash)
==4518==    by 0x41DD92: ??? (in /usr/bin/bash)
==4518==    by 0x41C482: main (in /usr/bin/bash)
```

Comment: What is the point of this question without any source code?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The C code itself doesn't seem to be a problem, as I said it runs without any leaks, the problem is in the bash script and not in the C code. Also, the C code is a few thousand lines long, and as it doesn't appear to have any issues I would have no idea what to include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`valgrind ./run` will debug the *shell* and not your program.

Take a look at the output, see how it mentions (e.g.)

> ==4518==    by 0x41C482: main (**in /usr/bin/bash**)

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

If you want to debug your program, you need to run `valgrind` *in* the script:

```
arg1=thing1
arg2=thing2

valgrind ./Coupled $thing1 $thing2
```

Comment: So is the reachable memory leak expected in that case? Just worried in case it is a subtlety in bash programming I'm missing as I know very little! The difference with the valgrind running makes sense though, thanks!

Comment: @DanielJ Unless you want to debug Bash and send bug-reports to the Bash maintainers, there's no need to worry about it. Bash is complicated, and as such it *will* contain bugs. It is also likely that some things that might be seen as bugs by outsiders like us really aren't, and the reports are false positives. More importantly, running Valgrind on Bash doesn't say *anything* about your program!